# Decorator pattern using Castle Windsor when different class need to be injected depending on caller

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I want to use decorator pattern using Castle Windsor to create view model for my api, but having different classes injected into decorators depending on controller. I have two versions of api endpoint.

One for HomeV1Controller:

```
public class HomeV1Controller : ApiController {
    private readonly IHomeViewModelFactory _factory;

    public HomeV1Controller(IHomeViewModelFactory factory) {
        _factory = factory;
    }
}
```

and second:

```
public class HomeV2Controller : ApiController {
    private readonly IHomeViewModelFactory _factory;

    public HomeV2Controller(IHomeViewModelFactory factory) {
        _factory = factory;
    }
}
```

both controllers accepts `IHomeViewModelFactory` which it definitions is:

```
public interface IHomeViewModelFactory {
   HomeViewModel CreateViewModel(); 
}
```

now I would like to inject common view model factory for both controllers and that factory need to call next view model factory which is specific for controller. So I have a factories:

Common:

```
public class UserViewModelFactory : IHomeViewModelFactory {
    private readonly IHomeViewModelFactory _factory;

    public UserViewModelFactory(IHomeViewModelFactory factory) {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public HomeViewModel CreateViewModel() {
        var vm = _factory.CreateViewModel();
        vm.User = new User();
        return vm;
    }
}
```

and two specific for controller:

```
public class HomeV1ViewModelFactory : IHomeViewModelFactory {
    public HomeViewModel CreateViewModel() {
        // logic only for V1 to create vm
        var vm = new HomeViewModel {
            Articles = new Articles()
        };
        return vm;
    }
}

public class HomeV2ViewModelFactory: IHomeViewModelFactory {
    public HomeViewModel CreateViewModel() {
        // logic only for V2 to create vm
        var vm = new HomeViewModel {
            Issues = new Issues()
        };
        return vm;
    }
}
```

Now the `HomeV1Controller` needs to have injected `UserViewModelFactory` which has dependency of `HomeV1ViewModelFactory` and `HomeV2Controller` needs to have injected `UserViewModelFactory` which has dependency of `HomeV2ViewModelFactory`.

Comment: Typically, we don't put any business logic in ViewModels and therefore there is no reason to mock them or to go back to the DI container to create them. Using the `new` keyword will suffice. See [this blog post](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97) for more details.

Comment: @NightOwl888 I dont put any logic in to view model itself. But logic I ment how vm is created.

Comment: That's good. My point is that there is no reason to use a factory or DI container to create your view models. You don't need an abstraction in this scenario. The code you have looks fine (except for the unnecessary `IHomeViewModelFactory` constructor parameter).

Comment: And what kind of IHomeViewModelFactory dependency do expect HomeV1ViewModelFactory and HomeV2ViewModelFactory?

Comment: @JanMuncinsky None, there is end of decorator. I will update the examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only thing I can think of is service override:

```
        container.Register(Component.For<HomeV1Controller>()
            .DependsOn(Property.ForKey<IHomeViewModelFactory>().Is("UserViewModelFactory1")));
        container.Register(Component.For<HomeV2Controller>()
            .DependsOn(Property.ForKey<IHomeViewModelFactory>().Is("UserViewModelFactory2")));

        container.Register(Component.For<IHomeViewModelFactory>()
            .ImplementedBy<UserViewModelFactory>()
            .Named("UserViewModelFactory1")
            .DependsOn(Property.ForKey<IHomeViewModelFactory>().Is("HomeV1ViewModelFactory")));

        container.Register(Component.For<IHomeViewModelFactory>()
            .ImplementedBy<UserViewModelFactory>()
            .Named("UserViewModelFactory2")
            .DependsOn(Property.ForKey<IHomeViewModelFactory>().Is("HomeV2ViewModelFactory")));

        container.Register(Component.For<IHomeViewModelFactory>().ImplementedBy<HomeV1ViewModelFactory>().Named("HomeV1ViewModelFactory"));
        container.Register(Component.For<IHomeViewModelFactory>().ImplementedBy<HomeV2ViewModelFactory>().Named("HomeV2ViewModelFactory"));
```